# how can I get height and width of a photo that I downloaded from internet in Java?

Tags: java

I'm downloading a photo from url address with the following code:

```
try(InputStream in = new URL(photoURL).openStream()){
    Files.copy(in, Paths.get("\\outputFiles\\photo.jpg"));
    System.out.println(outputDir+newPhotoURL);
}
```

But how can I additionaly display `width` and `height` of that image?

Comment: @AxelH how can I create an image object first to get its width and height?

Comment: By reading the 11 answers of the duplicate question I have linked ? you have the file ... if this is a small image, create the ImageBuffered with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BufferedImage` it has methods `getHeight()` & `getWidth()` in Java 7.

[BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

Code for the same :

```
BufferedImage imo;
        try {
            imo = ImageIO.read(new File("location_of_file"));
            System.out.println(imo.getHeight());
            System.out.println(imo.getWidth());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```